# jQuery Flexslider plugin with Reverie wordpress framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, flexslider

Hello stack overflow,

I am trying to implement the flex slider plugin on a wordpress blog, using the one described int his tutorial http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-slider-plugin-with-flexslider/, but cant seem to get it to work when using the Reverie wordpress framework, http://themefortress.com/reverie/ . If I change to another theme the plugin works fine.

The page concerned can be seen at http://www.naused.co.uk/test-slider-page/

In the console i get the error Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'flexslider', but I cant see why it would say that, I think the plugin is being used correctly. Could it be a Javascript conflict with something else on the page?

Originally I thought it might be a css issue as you can see the images are being brought in but the list items, do not have any styling applied to them by the javascript. In the example they are

```
 <ul class="slides">
  <li><img width="151" height="151" src="http://www.naused.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/nausedLogo.png" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="nausedLogo" title="nausedLogo"></li>
  <li><img width="970" height="406" src="http://www.naused.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/bannerHolder1.jpg" class="attachment-large wp-post-image" alt="bannerHolder" title="bannerHolder"></li>
 </ul>
```

and the list items are meant to have in-line styling applied to them by the flexslider plugin.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I have this sorted now. I had to rewrite the plugin and had to place the JavaScript and CSS files for `flexlslider` at the bottom of the page. I also had to use the `$` sign instead of jQuery which i don't understand, but never mind.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out the WP Orbit Slider.
Orbit is a lightweight slider made by Zurb.  The people who also built the framework for Reverie.

It is great, as you can create slide categories also.

Vaughnn